# Remote desktop connection different networks password non VPN

Tags: authentication, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a solution to bring support to users from a big network to other users into little networks. The idea is to keep control of content (no VPN). Also it's important that always users who need the service authorise technicien's access (protect the password).

I was looking for some solutions as tightvnc, but the problem is the password used is defined only during the installation. At this moment, if a technicien install the application to users, he will know the password for everybody. The idea is to have a possibility to create a PIN each connection (or use AD autorisation with user's information), and the user must contact the technicien and autorise his connection. (We don't want the technicien to be able to connect to any PC without permission).

I found some solutions (teamviewer, Chrome, etc), but the problem is all use VPN or SSL. Our main goal is to protect the big network and not the final user into the little network.

Is a solution that I could adapt to do this (better if free, but not a must)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why VPN is an obstacle. How does using a VPN compromise control of content?   What do you mean by "protect the big network and not the final user into the little network."